# nginx serve static files and change route/path

Tags: nginx

I want to serve static file with nginx from a directory like /data/content/video/ from a url route thats totally different like www.url.com/reports/video-name.mp4

I have tried several rewriting rules and locations but nothing seems to be working as I intend, is this at all possible?

this works with the video name as the only route parameter (e.g www.url.com/video-name.mp4):

```
location ~ \.(mp4) {
        root /data/content/video;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        proxy_buffering off;
        mp4;
        mp4_buffer_size 4M;
        mp4_max_buffer_size 10M;
}
```

Is there a rewrite rule or regex that i could use to pull out the video-name.mp4 so that the file it tries to serve is: `/data/content/video/video-name.mp4` from this request `www.url.com/reports/video-name.mp4`

Answer (score 3):

The key to the answer is likely your location definition. This probably won't work perfectly, but it should give you a clue to work it out yourself.

```
location ~* /reports/ {
  root /data/content/video;
  // etc
}
```

Your question isn't particularly clear, so if this isn't answering the question you meant to ask I suggest you edit the question.

Comment: so that tries to serve a file from `/data/content/video/reports/video-name.mp4` I would like to get it to serve `/data/content/video-name.mp4` I am trying to strip the route out of it except for the video name itself.... sorry kind of hard to explain

Comment: I get you now. You'll have to use a regular expression with an appropriate capture group. I could work it out, given enough time, but last time it took me hours. With that clue maybe you can work it out yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `root` inside `location` blocks, since it causes confusing situations.

You need to use `alias` directive. With `root`, the server appends the complete URI to the directory specified with the directive. With `alias`, you can append any portion of the filename to the directory.

Try this:

```
location ~ /reports/+.mp4$ {
    alias /data/content/video;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best option, but i did get this to work using a rewrite in the block like this:

```
location ~ \.(mp4) {
        rewrite ^(.*)/reports/(.*)$ $1/$2;
        root /data/content/video;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        proxy_buffering off;
        mp4;
        mp4_buffer_size 4M;
        mp4_max_buffer_size 10M;
}
```

Figured I'd share.